# Azure DevOps pipeline - terraform using service connection

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to create Azure DevOps pipeline to deploy some resources.
As the main point of this deployment, I need to use Service Connection.
My problem is that configuration set in task `Terraform Init` do not apply to task with `Terraform Plan`. Is there any way to make all those tasks be done in one "environment" without making them into a single task or repeating

```
        export ARM_CLIENT_ID=$servicePrincipalId
        export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=$servicePrincipalKey
        export ARM_TENANT_ID=$tenantId
        export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=$(az account show | jq -r .id)
```

block of code.

Pipeline yaml file:

```yaml
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: Terraform
      type: git
      name: DIF_pipelines
      ref: main
      trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"

variables:
  - group: Dev

steps:
  - checkout: Terraform
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: "Create Resource Group"
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: "datahub-dev-armsc-01"
      scriptType: "bash"
      scriptLocation: "inlineScript"
      inlineScript: |
        az group create \
          --name $(resource_group_name) \
          --location westeurope
      failOnStandardError: true

  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: "Terraform Init"
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: "datahub-dev-armsc-01"
      scriptType: "bash"
      scriptLocation: "inlineScript"
      inlineScript: |
        echo "Setting up variables"
        export ARM_CLIENT_ID=$servicePrincipalId
        export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=$servicePrincipalKey
        export ARM_TENANT_ID=$tenantId
        export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=$(az account show | jq -r .id)
        cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(env)/terraform/init
        terraform init \
          -backend-config="client_id=$ARM_CLIENT_ID" \
          -backend-config="client_secret=$ARM_CLIENT_SECRET" \
          -backend-config="tenant_id=$ARM_TENANT_ID" \
          -backend-config="subscription_id=$ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"
      addSpnToEnvironment: true
      failOnStandardError: true

  - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
    name: SSHPubKey
    displayName: "Download SSH Pub key"
    inputs:
      secureFile: "GranGarden.pub"

  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: "Terraform Plan"
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: "datahub-dev-armsc-01"
      scriptType: "bash"
      scriptLocation: "inlineScript"
      inlineScript: |
        printenv
        cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(env)/terraform/init
        terraform plan -var 'ssh_key_path=${SSHPubKey.secureFilePath}' \
          -var-file=$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(env)/terraform/init/init_$(env).tfvars \
          -out=$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/init.plan
      failOnStandardError: true

  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: "Terraform Apply"
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: "datahub-dev-armsc-01"
      scriptType: "bash"
      scriptLocation: "inlineScript"
      inlineScript: |
        cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(env)/terraform/init
        pwd
        terraform apply $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/init.plan
      failOnStandardError: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the credentials from the service connection and set them on the stage level, each stage can have an individual runner/agent which is why it is better to export them in each stage.

#### Task config for exporting the Credentials from Service Connection.

```yaml
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Fetch credentials for azure
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(service_connection) ## in your case "datahub-dev-armsc-01"
    scriptType: bash
    addSpnToEnvironment: true # this will add the required credentials to env vars
    useGlobalConfig: true
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_TENANT_ID;]$tenantId"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_ID;]$servicePrincipalId"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_SECRET;]$servicePrincipalKey"
```

once you do this all jobs within that stage can have access to the Azure SPN credentials as env vars and further terraform can use them with respect to [configuring-the-service-principal-in-terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_secret#configuring-the-service-principal-in-terraform).

- [azurecli@2 Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines)
- [Set variables in Scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash)

Comment: Thank you, yesterday during the night I stumbled upon similar solution.